# Use multiple SQL query results in one SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a project with two MySQL tables;

- LedgerSchedule
- GeneralLedger

The first table LedgerSchedule contains the possible types which are used in GeneralLedger. Each record from GeneralLedger can be a CREDIT or DEBIT transaction (from type LedgerSchedule).

Now if i want to create a transaction survey with GeneralLedger transactions i run three queries in my project;

- Select possible LedgerSchedule's
- Select CREDIT GeneralLedgers for each LedgerSchedule
- Select DEBIT GeneralLedgers for each LedgerSchedule

After this three queries i save the (DEBIT-CREDIT) amounts back to each LedgerSchedule.
This works, but it is slow (especially when there are many LedgerSchedule's).
To speed things up, i want to accomplish this with one MySQL query.

Summarised i want to Select LedgerSchedule's with their CREDIT/DEBIT GeneralLedgers amounts in one query.

A first attempt (in this example i select only the ID from LedgerSchedule);

[image]

But this selects only the GeneralLedgers with DEBIT and CREDIT transactions. Changing this to

```
WHERE LS.ID = DEBIT.ID
OR LS.ID = CREDIT.ID
```

Isn't working either. Next to this i also want to select the LedgerSchedule's without any GeneralLedgers DEBIT/CREDIT transactions.

```
| LedgerSchedule | Debit   | Credit  |
|       1        | €30.00  |         |
|       2        |         | €23.45  |
|       3        |         |         |
|       4        | €15.15  | €10.00  |
|       5        |         |         |
```

How can i accomplish this? Maybe even without multiple Selects in one query ...

Comment: Jeeez all that capitalisation makes your SQL a pain to read, there's a general preference that variables in a SQL (such as column names) are lower case and only Control words, such as "SELECT" are in upper case, it makes it all much more readable....

Comment: The same reason is also why Road signs are not in upper case, it's `HARDER (SLOWER) TO UNDERSTAND UPPER CASE WRITTEN TEXT BLOCKS`.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select gl.ledger_schedule_id,
       sum(case when gl.debit_credit = 1 then gl.amount else - gl.amount
           end) as net
from GeneralLedger gl
group by gl.ledger_schedule_id;
```

If `debit_credit` could take on a value other than 0 or 1, you'll want a `where` clause to prevent overcounting.

If you want the amounts separately:

```
select gl.ledger_schedule_id,
       sum(case when gl.debit_credit = 1 then gl.amount end) as credit,
       sum(case when gl.debit_credit = 0 then gl.amount end) as debit
from GeneralLedger gl
group by gl.ledger_schedule_id;
```

Comment: Thats a nice approach Gordon, but i need to show the debit and credit amounts before i calculate the totals for each LedgerSchedule.

The query result needs to be all LedgerSchedule's and debit and/or credit amounts for each LedgerSchedule if available.

Comment: Indeed, just use conditional aggregation :)